# How to Expand Cells to Match Full Table Width

Tags: css, html

I'm using divs that behave like a table for media query/responsive design. The cells are brown and the underlying table is orange. Trying to get the brown cells to expand horizontally to match the full width of the orange table. As it is, the orange is wider. Thank you for any help.

```
<style type=text/css>

.formwidth{background-color: orange;}
.Cell, .Cell_fullwidth {
    text-align: left;
display: table-cell;
    border: none;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
vertical-align: top;}

   .formCell{height:29px; background-color: brown;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1550px) {

.Cell, .Cell_makewide {float: left;}
.Cell_fullwidth    {float: left;}
.Cell_screenwidth    {float: left;}
.Cell    {  width:47%; float: left; }
.Cell_makewide    {float: left;}
.Cell_screenwidth    {width: 100%; float: left;}

.Cell_fullwidth    {width: 100%; float: left;}
.mainTable{width:708px;}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 745px) {

.mainTable{width: 85%;}
    .Cell    {width:95%; float: left;}

}
</style>

<html><body>

<div class="Table mainTable">
<div class="Row">
<div class="Cell_fullwidth formwidth">  



<div class="Table">



<div class=Row>        
<div class="Cell formCell">Your name:</div>
<div class="Cell formCell">
<input class=boxwidth type=text name="your_name"></div>
</div>


<div class=Row>
<div class="Cell formCell">Email:</div>
<div class="Cell formCell">
<input class=boxwidth type=text name="email_address"></div>
</div>

<div class=Row>
<div class="Cell formCell">Phone:</div>
<div class="Cell formCell">
<input class=boxwidth type=text name="home_phone"></div>
</div>


<div class=Row>        
<div class="Cell formCell">When visiting:</div>
<div class="Cell formCell">
<input class=boxwidth type=text name="Visit_Date"></div>
</div>

<div class=Row>
<div class="Cell formCell">When moving:</div>
<div class="Cell formCell">
<input class=boxwidth type=text name="Moving_Date"></div>
</div>

<div class=Row>
<div class="Cell formCell">I describe myself as:</div>
<div class="Cell formCell">
    <select class=boxwidth name="Number_Moving">
    <option>Select Category</option>
    <option>Just Browsing</option>
        <option>Consideringe</option>
    <option>Ready to Go</option>
        <option>an Investor</option>
        <option>Already Bought</option>
        </select>
</div>
</div>

<div class=Row>        
<div class="Cell formCell">Area of Tucson:</div>
<div class="Cell formCell">
    <select class=boxwidth name="Where_in_Tucson">
        <option>Select Area</option>
    <option>Tucson</option>
        <option>Oro Valley</option>
            <option>Marana</option>
        <option>Catalina Foothills</option>
        <option>University</option>
    <option>NorthEast</option>
        <option>NorthWest</option>
        <option>SouthEast</option>
        <option>SouthWest</option>
        <option>Downtown</option>
    <option>East</option>
        <option>West</option>
        <option>Central</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div> <!--end row --!>


<div class=Row>        
<div class="Cell formCell">I have a home to sell:</div>
<div class="Cell formCell">
<input type=radio name=Home_to_sell value=yes>yes
<input type=radio name=home_to_sell value=no>no</div>
</div>


</div>



</div> <!--end table --!>

 </body></html>
```

This css may help, but it doesn't seem to have intended effect:

.Table  {display: table; border: none;       border: solid; border-width: thin; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}

.Row{display: table-row;}

Thank you

Comment: There are actually 2 embedded tables in this code. Removing the outside table had the desired effect of aligning the cells. However, I actually want the two embedded because there's a second table I want to include that's not shown here. Trying to understand how to get the embedded table  to match the width of the outside table. Thank you.

Comment: where's your table? this is not a full example